# Convert string to mongo query format

Tags: javascript, json, loopbackjs

I am trying to build advance search functionality. I want to convert the input string into mongodb query format.

for example, the input

```
'status = confirmed AND (assignee = xyz OR priority = low)'
```

Should be converted to output:

```
{
  and : [{
    status : 'confirmed'  
  }, {
    or: [
      {assignee: xyz},
      {priority: low}
    ]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Will there be nested parenthesis? `(assignee = xyz OR (priority = low AND prop = 100))`

Comment: Post the code that you attempted.

Comment: @adiga - yes there is nested parenthesis.

Comment: @PrerakSola - I have not attempted for nesting query. I am sharing the code for flat query - https://codeshare.io/a3qgp6